Deduplication , Grouping for events table at scale
I'm working with an events table where different source tables trigger writes into this table with columns: entity_id and payload. These events are then published to a Kafka topic using a message relay service. The table is partitioned hourly based on event_time, handling a high scale of ~5M+ rows per hour. After a row is processed and published, we mark it as processed=true and drop partitions after 24 hours to avoid performance issues from deleting individual rows.
I need a way to add deduplication to this table. Specifically, if an unprocessed row with the same entity_id and entity_type already exists, I want to update the payload instead of adding multiple events.
Also I am fetching rows as where processed=false order by event_time asc limit 1000; Is there a way to fetch grouping by entity_type?
Is there an efficient technique to achieve deduplication at insertion and grouping by entity_type at fetch at this at scale?
Table:
Create events ( 
  id Big serial not null, 
  entity_type text not null, #source table identifier 
  entity_id text not null, #source table pk 
  event_time timestamps default current_time, 
  payload json, 
  processed boolean default false, 
  Primary key (id, event_time) 
) partition by range (event_time)

Stack: Database: Postgres, Partition management: pgpartman, Relay service: Java

'I need a way to add deduplication to this table' sounds like a solution, not a problem. What's the actual problem you're trying to solve? How far short of required performance are random look-ups to check for duplicates on your system?

we are at high scale of 5M events per hour. These events are CDC events. Service listen and send data to kafka lets say (debezium is not an options for us). no when we get frequent update for same entity_id it doesn't make sense to update same data 5 times. Instead do once if processed is false.

'it doesn't make sense to update same data 5 times' - well that depends. I hear what you're saying. Do you have some stats to share about how often such duplicates occur? ~5M per hour might not reflect the technical challenge. It's only ~1400 / sec on average, is this fast enough to deal with worst case scenarios? Random look-ups might take 10 or more times longer than sequential writes, so when it makes sense to do it depends on the stats.

In recent cases we saw updates of 5 to 8 times per hour In avg. Even avg of 3 duplicates made process required rows to : 15M. Irrespective of duplicate count we are looking for solution for deduplication and majorly grouping by entity_type because most of logic for downstream have entity_type based make it better to batch multiple ids in a message to increase throughput at complete system level

You can use the ON CONFLICT clause available in PostgreSQL to perform an upsert. This allows you to update the existing row if a conflict on entity_id and entity_type occurs instead of inserting a duplicate row. https://jonmeyers.io/blog/use-on-conflict-to-upsert-in-postgresql/
